# How to Swipe activity in android wear apps?

Tags: android, wear-os

I am creating a Android Wear app that has a main activity and another setting activity, how i can display the setting activity when the user swipe the screen from right to left when he on the main activity ? something thing like this picture .

[image: Example]

Comment: Have you considered using just `ViewPager` with two `Fragments` inside? Is there any reason why you would want to use two `Activities` here?

Comment: @MaciejCiemięga no there is no reason for using activities , i will trying the fragments , and i`ll be back . Thank you for your advice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use android.support.v4.view.ViewPager just like you do in normal Android apps.